# Group to column and fill columns with unique ranking row

Tags: sql, oracle

I am basing a query on a table that has, say, results of events. Each row has a team that participated and their resulting placement for that event (max 4 teams participate). I want to run a query based on this that will group to the event and creates a column for each placement and fills it with the team that got that rank during that event.

For this I have created fields (first_place, second_place, etc.) that check a conditional case statement against the rank column and if the team got the result corresponding to that column it would fill the column with that team's name.

The problem I am running into is that if I don't add the cases to the group it errors out (at least in Oracle, SQL Fiddle handles it but still wrong result). If I add them to the group clause it then outputs 1 row for each team and rank with the rest of the columns NULL.

This makes sense for the grouping to work like this but can't seem to find a workaround. I was trying to use something like COALESCE but nothing that I could find works like this as an aggregate function.

SQL Fiddle and DDL below for your reference. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ae4c9/1

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`pk_id` int, `evt_id` int, `team` varchar(5), `rank` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`pk_id`, `evt_id`, `team`, `rank`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'TeamA', 1),
    (2, 1, 'TeamB', 2),
    (3, 1, 'TeamC', 3),
    (4, 1, 'TeamD', 4),
    (5, 2, 'TeamD', 1),
    (6, 2, 'TeamB', 2),
    (7, 2, 'TeamC', 3),
    (8, 2, 'TeamA', 4),
    (9, 3, 'TeamB', 1),
    (10, 3, 'TeamD', 2),
    (11, 3, 'TeamC', 3),
    (12, 3, 'TeamA', 4),
    (13, 4, 'TeamD', 1),
    (14, 4, 'TeamC', 2),
    (15, 4, 'TeamA', 3),
    (16, 4, 'TeamB', 4)
;
```

Query

```
SELECT
  evt_id,
  CASE rank WHEN 1 THEN team END as first_place,
  CASE rank WHEN 2 THEN team END as second_place,
  CASE rank WHEN 3 THEN team END as third_place,
  CASE rank WHEN 4 THEN team END as fourth_place
FROM
  Table1
GROUP BY
  evt_id
;
```

Current Results

```
+--------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| evt_id | first_place | second_place | third_place | fourth_place |
+--------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
|      1 | TeamA       | (null)       | (null)      | (null)       |
|      1 | (null)      | TeamB        | (null)      | (null)       |
|      1 | (null)      | (null)       | TeamC       | (null)       |
|      1 | (null)      | (null)       | (null)      | TeamD        |
|      2 | TeamD       | (null)       | (null)      | (null)       |
|      2 | (null)      | TeamB        | (null)      | (null)       |
|      2 | (null)      | (null)       | TeamC       | (null)       |
|      2 | (null)      | (null)       | (null)      | TeamA        |
|      3 | TeamB       | (null)       | (null)      | (null)       |
|      3 | (null)      | TeamD        | (null)      | (null)       |
|      3 | (null)      | (null)       | TeamC       | (null)       |
|      3 | (null)      | (null)       | (null)      | TeamA        |
|      4 | TeamD       | (null)       | (null)      | (null)       |
|      4 | (null)      | TeamC        | (null)      | (null)       |
|      4 | (null)      | (null)       | TeamA       | (null)       |
|      4 | (null)      | (null)       | (null)      | TeamB        |
+--------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Expected Output

```
+--------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| evt_id | first_place | second_place | third_place | fourth_place |
+--------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
|      1 | TeamA       | TeamB        | TeamC       | TeamD        |
|      2 | TeamD       | TeamB        | TeamC       | TeamA        |
|      3 | TeamB       | TeamD        | TeamC       | TeamA        |
|      4 | TeamD       | TeamC        | TeamA       | TeamB        |
+--------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Comment: No, I am using Oracle SQL Developer. The sample was done in SQL Fiddle just as a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want some aggregation functions:

```
SELECT evt_id,
       MAX(CASE rank WHEN 1 THEN team END) as first_place,
       MAX(CASE rank WHEN 2 THEN team END) as second_place,
       MAX(CASE rank WHEN 3 THEN team END) as third_place,
       MAX(CASE rank WHEN 4 THEN team END) as fourth_place
FROM Table1
GROUP BY evt_id;
```

Comment: Can you do a MAX() on a non-numerical field?

Comment: @nbayly . . . Absolutely.